# Viewbox disappears on restoring the WPF window down

Tags: wpf, xaml, viewbox

I have a `Viewbox` Control that contains a `WindowsFormsHost` which in turn acts as a container to display images.

```
<Viewbox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Stretch="Fill" MinHeight="50" MinWidth="50">
   <WindowsFormsHost  Width="100" Height="100" Name="ImageSegment" Background="Black"/>
</Viewbox>
```

With the above code, the `ViewBox` appears and resizes accordingly.
  But the `Viewbox` disappears once it is restored down to a below specified `Width`.

```
<Viewbox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Stretch="Fill" Height="875" Width="975">
   <WindowsFormsHost  Width="100" Height="100" Name="ImageSegment" Background="Black"/> 
</Viewbox>
```

If i give it this way, `Viewbox` stays, but its auto-scaling property is lost.
  Is there a way to get around this problem? Why it occurs?
  Thanks in Advance!

Comment: I don't think putting a WinformsHost inside a ViewBox is a good idea at all.

Comment: @HighCore: I'm using WinformsHost to host a container that displays images and that container is a control of type Winforms

Comment: then remove the Viewbox.